# How to transform a sum in an integral

Tags: calculus

I have the following equation:
$$z(\rho)=\int_0^{R}\frac{A}{\left(\rho+\rho_0\right)^\alpha}cos(\omega\rho)dx$$
where:
$\rho=\sqrt{\left( x+\Delta s)^2+y^2 \right)}$ with $\rho_0$ constant,
$\rho_0\in\mathbb{R}$, $\alpha$ constant, $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$,
$0\le\Delta s\le \Delta s_0$. Because $x^2+y^2=R^2$, the $\rho$ is function only of $x$.
If I want to transform the quantity $\Delta s$ in $ds$, I get:
$\rho=\sqrt{\left( x+ds)^2+(R^2-x^2) \right)}$
How can I calculate the integral:
$$\int_0^{\Delta s_0}z(\rho)ds$$